# Put select statement in a for loop - sql

Tags: sql, oracle, loops, select, plsql

I have a select statement on a table, but I want to run it line by line in a for loop. Tried bind variables etc but it's not solving the issue. Any suggestions?

Here is my code:

Assume I need to print column1 from table line by line. But I get error - bind variable line not defined. What's the correct way?

```
DECLARE
  A NUMBER (2);
  R1 NUMBER(2);
  LINE VARCHAR(1000);
BEGIN
  SELECT MAX(ROWNUM) 
  INTO R1 
  FROM TABLE1 
  <<R_LOOP>> 
  FOR I IN 1...R1 LOOP
    INSERT INTO LINE 
    SELECT COLUMN1 
    FROM TABLE1 
    WHERE ROWNUN=I 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(LINE)
  END LOOP R_LOOP 
END; 
/
```

Comment: What data base?

Comment: Just something on a society network in my locality. Doesn't matter. Its a small db with 3 tables.

Comment: From the `sql` tag: "Questions should include code examples, table structure, sample data, and a tag for the DBMS implementation (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, etc.) being used". Please **[edit]** the question to include these details (don't use comments for it).

Comment: We need your RDBMS name

Comment: Are you really sure you need a loop? Often in SQL there is a way to do "it" in a single statement that performs better.

Comment: FYI: where the database is hosted ("in my locality") is not really important. But the type of database (Oracle, MS SQL Server, ...) _is_ as syntax differs between them.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some [sample data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: The code as posted won't compile because all the lines are missing terminating semi-colons. Also, it doesn't contain any bind variable, so it's not the actual code you ran. If you want us to help you need to post coherent code.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking after CURSOR, this is an object that is browsing your table line after line.

```
cursor c1 IS
SELECT column1, column2 FROM ... ;

OPEN c1;
LOOP
    FETCH c1 INTO column1_c, column2_c;

        ...

    EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
END LOOP;
```

I'm not sure at 100% for the syntax of your RDBMS. Maybe you can find more on the SQL Developer documentation.

[Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/cursor_declaration.htm)

Comment: 'Select * from ' is done. Where do u insert table name to print?

Comment: Your select statement is after the `IS`, I edited my answer.

Comment: If I have to print select column1 from table where rownum =i. Run i from 1 to 100. Not sure how to implement this

Answer (score 0):

assuming the database is oracle...as per the loop function it is executed line by line only. no need to separately initialize  to fetch line by line. you can have the following reference...

```
declare
cursor c1 is <select column1 statement>;
...
begin
...
for rec in c1
loop
.......
insert into LINE values (rec.column1);
......
end loop;
commit;
end;
```

all the loop statements are executed record by record only.

ans as stated in your question,
if you used like

```
 SELECT COLUMN1 
    FROM TABLE1 
    WHERE ROWNUN=I
```

this will return value only when rownum=1....
when we having other conditions like rownum=2, rownum=3..... it won't return any results unless the table has column name 'ROWNUM'.. Rownum is a dynamically generated based on the results fetched by the select cursor, and hence direct fetching like rownum=2 fails, where you can have as rownum<=2 and have work around...
i suggest to use loop functionality to have record by record operations...

Answer (score 0):

I hope you can achieve it using `returning` clause as shown below. Hope this helps.

```
    DECLARE
      A NUMBER (2);
      R1 NUMBER(2);
      TYPE t_tab IS TABLE OF LINE.COLUMN1%TYPE;
      l_tab t_tab;
    BEGIN
      SELECT MAX(ROWNUM)+1
      INTO R1 
      FROM TABLE1;
        INSERT INTO LINE 
        SELECT COLUMN1 
        FROM TABLE1 
        WHERE ROWNUM < R1
        RETURNING COLUMN1  BULK COLLECT INTO l_tab;

       FOR i IN l_tab.first .. l_tab.last LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(l_tab(i));
       END LOOP;    
       END; 
       /
```